# Plotly Dash: How to debug "Error loading layout"?

Tags: python, debugging, plotly-dash

When writing code for Dash, you usually have to write an `app.layout`. Errors made here only appear when running the app, and sometimes give the mostly useless "Error loading layout" message.

There are already [quite a few questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=dash%20%22error%20loading%20layout%22) in stackoverflow asking about this "Error loading layout", and usually, there is either no answer or an answer where the error in the code is pointed out.

**But how would you narrow down where the error is?**
In coding, usually, we get at least some hint like in which line an error occurs. In plain HTML, we can see which line causes problems. But `app.layout` is basically a complete HTML layout in "one line" - is there any way to narrow down what exactly went wrong?

#### Edit:

I was basing this question on the assumption that Dash itself was responsible for this error, while I now realize that this might be a problem with the underlying `dash-table` package, which is why no error is shown in dash's debug menu. See this issue on github: https://github.com/plotly/dash-table/issues/912

Answer (score 3):

If you run in [debug mode](https://dash.plotly.com/devtools), you will usually get a useful error message. This code for example,

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html

app = dash.Dash()
app.layout = html.Div([["Hello world"]])  # list of lists as children, a typical syntax error

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

yields the following error message in Dash 1.2.0,

[image: Error log]

EDIT: The particular issue that you are seeing occurs in the Python layer. If you set `debug=False` you should see the error in the Python console,

```
TypeError: Object of type NAType is not JSON serializable
```

Any data passed to Dash must be JSON serializable, and the `NAType` object is not. Hence you should replace it with a JSON serializable alternative,

```
df.fillna(value=np.nan, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, this does not answer my question. Your error is recognized by dash and even with debug turned off, the page simply does not load instead of displaying *"Error loading layout"* . *Error loading layout* is caused by different things it seems, and harder to debug.

Comment: Edit: I am now realizing the problem might not be with Dash itself, but with the `dash-table` package. See this issue on github for a reference (I will also post the code to the question): https://github.com/plotly/dash-table/issues/912